# Скрыть дочернии элементы одного элемента и показать дочернии элементы другого при клике

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

Нужно скрыть элементы `.tp-revslider-slidesli` при клике по `.tparrows` и показать элементы `.tp-revslider-slidesli-2` и наоборот. То есть нужно, чтобы они менялись при каждом клике. Делал так(см. код), но что-то не получается. Первый блок `.tp-revslider-slidesli` исчезает и появляется сразу же, а второй блок скрыт постоянно.

```
$('.tparrows').click(function () {
  $('.tp-revslider-slidesli').find(".tp-parallax-wrap").toggle(500);
  $('.tp-revslider-slidesli-2').find(".tp-parallax-wrap").toggle(500);                  
});
```

Comment: ошибки нет, покажите html и css

Answer (score 1):

Как видите ваш код работает.

```js
$('.tparrows').click(function () {
  $('.tp-revslider-slidesli, .tp-revslider-slidesli-1').find(".tp-parallax-wrap").toggle(500);
});
```

```css
.slide {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.slide::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.slider > div {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  background: #ddd;
}

.tp-parallax-wrap {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="slider">
  <div class="tp-revslider-slidesli">
    <div class="tp-parallax-wrap"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tp-revslider-slidesli-1">
    <div class="tp-parallax-wrap" style="display: none;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<input type="button" class="tparrows" value="Поменять">
```

Скорее всего, как предположил [@Alex](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/966151/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80#comment1618993_966151), у вас ошибка в html.